# ng completion no longer exists

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

Just updated to use the latest version of Angular CLI (6.0).

How to setup bash completion for the ng binary?
It used to be

```
. <(ng completion --bash)
```

in the `~/.bashrc` file, but now no longer.

Can this still be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v6.0.0) post:

> The completion command has been removed as the functionality no longer aligns with this version.

You can find a Github ticket for this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11043).

As a Workaround you can run this in your command line:

```
NG_COMMANDS="add build config doc e2e generate help lint new run serve test update version xi18n"
complete -W "$NG_COMMANDS" ng
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Angular CLI v13.0.2, the up-to-date completion command is as follows:

```
complete -W "\
  add \
  analytics \
  build \
  deploy \
  config \
  doc \
  e2e \
  extract-i18n \
  generate \
  help \
  lint \
  new \
  run \
  serve \
  test \
  update \
  version" \
  ng
```