# When I open the terminal shows "The specified command("completion") is invalid. For a list of available options, run "ng help"

Tags: angular, terminal, iterm2

When I open the terminal did't do anything. It will shows errors as below.

[image]

Comment: Did you check your startup (`~/.bashrc`?) file?

Comment: It may be caused because your global angular CLI is not correct version (@14)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I had the same error after updating angular every time after opening the terminal.

Depending on which terminal you use either open configuration file which will be saved in ~/.bashrc, or for zshell ~/.zshrc, and so on for others,

Edit the corresponding `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file and delete or comment this line:

```
source <(ng completion script)
```

Sadly you will lose the angular autocompletion, but it looks like there is some bug causing this in their implementation

Comment: Follow this post to replace their completion script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194674/ng-completion-no-longer-exists

Comment: in mac vim ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 24):

According to [angular.io](https://angular.io/cli/completion), `ng completion` will help you in command line mode. So, if you face the problem, you can try to fix it rather than simply remove it. This command works in Angular 14.

First you should try to upgrade your `@angular/cli` by below commands:

```bash
npm uninstall @angular/cli
npm i --location=global @angular/cli
```

After this, you should try to open a new terminal, see if the problem still exists.

If yes, then probably you used a wrong `ng`, by running command `which ng`, it will tell you the "global" `ng` location. Almost 100 percent it is not the one you have just installed.

So you can just delete this `ng` and it's related `node_modules/@angular`, then re-install angular cli.

It should work now.

Comment: On Node 16, I had to do `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and then `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: @AliF50 proposal works also for **v14.19.1**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you upgrade your angular/cli to the latest version as suggested by Bryan. I was getting the same error but was able to resolve once I upgraded my angular cli version to latest

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33226297)